# Помогите с базами данных в SSMS

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть таблицы

1. Студенты
2. Преподаватели
3. Оценки
4. Типы оценок
5. Предметы
6. Нагрузка

Фотки таблицы здесь ---> https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/my-drive

И мне нужно создать представление содержащее, список специальностей с указанием количества имеющихся мест и количества поданных заявлений абитуриентов.
И вот я вроде написал запрос, но при попытке его сохранить выходит ошибка *Недопустимое имя столбца "номер_предмета"*. При создании представления я выбрал таблицы Предметы, Студенты и Нагрузка.

```
CREATE VIEW SpecialtiesView AS
SELECT
    P.номер_предмета,
    P.название_предмета,
    COUNT(S.номер_группы) AS количество_поданных_заявлений
FROM
    Предметы P
LEFT JOIN
    Студенты S ON P.номер_предмета = S.номер_предмета
GROUP BY
    P.номер_предмета, P.название_предмета;
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: *Фотки таблицы здесь* А мы не лечим по фотографии. [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120) [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)

Comment: вы на запрос то сам посмотрите, предметы джойнятся на студентов. таблица нагрузка там отсутствует. обращаетесь к полю `номер_предмета` у студента, вряд ли у него таковой есть. `COUNT(номер_группы)` тоже нечто странное, самих студентов считать надо бы, а не номера их групп.